# Postfix Header Checks

Tags: header, postfix-mta

Good morning everyone, I'm trying to create a rule of changing the FROM header on sent email.
My need is to change the FROM of all the mails that come from a specific mailbox (software@domain.com) and that have in CC the mail of a specific store (store04@domain.com).

For Example the mail sent to SMTP Server will have as FROM:software@domain.com, as CC:store@domain.com and as TO: customer@company.com, the mail that will have to exit need to have  header with FROM: store@domain.com and TO:customer@company.com only.

I already tested some rules in header checks config (/etc/postfix/header_checks) but without any working results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be good if you could share the contents of the `/etc/postfix/header_checks` file. That would give someting to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below might work:

```
if /^From: software@domain.com$/
    /^From: software@domain.com$/ REPLACE From: store@domain.com
    /^CC: store@domain.com$/ IGNORE
endif
```

I haven't tested this and I am by no means a Postfix expert, but from my reading of http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html, I think I have got all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment to Jacobs answer but want to add that http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html states

> ```
>           Note: do not prepend whitespace to patterns inside if..endif.
> ```